# Cauchy Integral Formula for a continuous function defined on a circle

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D$ be the open unit disc and $C$ be the unit circle. Suppose $$f:C\to\mathbb{C}$$
is continuous. Show that
$$g(w)=\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C} \dfrac{f(z)}{z-w} \rm{d}z$$
is an analytic function of $w$ for $w\in D$.

Not sure how to approach this, the fact that $f$ is only defined on $C$ is posing a problem.
The form that the RHS is in only reminds me of CIF...
Could someone give me a hint?

(ps wasn't sure what to put as the title, feel free to edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll leave it to you to verify that $g$ is continuous. Assuming that, let $\gamma$ be an arbitrary simple closed curve inside $D$. Then
\begin{align}
\int_\gamma g(w)\,dw &= \int_\gamma \left( \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{f(z)}{z-w}\,dz \right)\,dw \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \left( \int_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z-w}\,dw \right)\,dz\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C 0\,dz = 0
\end{align}
by Fubini's theorem and Cauchy's integral theorem (note that $\frac{f(z)}{z-w}$ is holomorphic in $w$; it's only singularity is at $w=z$, but $z \in C$ is *outside* $\gamma$).

Hence, Morera's theorem implies that $g$ is holomorphic on $D$.