# Prove $f(a) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{f(z)}{z - a}dz, C(\theta) = e^{i\theta}(0\le\theta\le 2 \pi), |a| = 1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Here's what I'm wondering.

> prove that :  $f(a) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{f(z)}{z - a}dz, C(\theta) = e^{i\theta}(0\le\theta\le 2 \pi), |a| = 1, a \in \mathbb{C}$ where $f(z)$ is continuous on $C$

I know that this statement is true when $a$ is strictly inside the unit disk but I'm lost how to find out the case when it's on the boundary. I posted original problem but didn't get the answer([here](https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-do-I-prove-that-g-z-oint_C-frac-f-t-t-z-dt-z-ne-1-C-e-i-theta-0-le-theta-le-2-pi-is-analytic-with-f-continuous-on-unit-circle-And-that-lim_-z-to-a-g-z-f-a-a-1-limit-taken-from-inside-the-unit-disc)) and it's the second part of it. I figured out to this point according to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3660630/easy-way-of-changing-order-of-complex-line-integral) post, and I used the same method(to show uniform convergence of the integrand) to prove that second part of original problem reduces to the problem I stated. Can you give me some help regarding this?

Comment: Well, you also need some assumptions on the function...don't you?

Comment: And after the above, check the lemma and in particular its corollary in the most upvoted answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83828/definite-integral-calculation-with-poles-at-0-and-pm-i-sqrt3/184874#184874 This is what you need.

Comment: @DonAntonio right.. I forgot the assumptions I'll add those

Comment: @DonAntonio And I'll check the lemma out!

Comment: When $a$ is on the boundary the integral is, in general, not convergent. Do you mean to take the P.V. of the integral?

Comment: @Caffeine what is P.V.?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value?wprov=sfla1

Comment: Well, I haven't heard of it but I'm sure that I don't mean P.V. but I mean the actual integral. The original problem goes like : How do I prove that $g(z) = \oint_C \frac{f(t)} {t - z} dt$ ($|z| \ne 1$, $C = e^ {I\theta}, 0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$) is analytic with $f$ continuous on unit circle? And that $\lim_ {z\to a} g(z) = f(a),|a| = 1$, limit taken from inside the unit disc?

Comment: @Caffeine And here, I showed the first part and reduced the second part which is computing the limit, and by uniform convergence of the integrand this became the problem I wrote above: prove or disprove :  $f(a) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{f(z)}{z - a}dz, C(\theta) = e^{i\theta}(0\le\theta\le 2 \pi), |a| = 1, a \in \mathbb{C}$ where $f(z)$ is continuous on $C$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $f(z)=1; a=1$. The integral is

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{ie^{i\vartheta}}{e^{i\vartheta}-1}d\vartheta=i\left(\int_0^{2\pi}1+\frac{1}{e^{i\vartheta}-1}d\vartheta\right)=\\
=2\pi i+i\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{e^{i\vartheta}-1}d\vartheta$$

The remaining integral is not convergent (as it is asymptotic to $1/\vartheta$ as $\vartheta\to 0$; $\vartheta\to 2\pi$)

As for your original problem, a hint:
The statement is true for constant functions. Thus, to prove that it is true for $f$, it suffices to prove it for $f-f(a)$. How does this simplify the problem?

Comment: You're saying that the original statement is true; Do you mean the original limit and the one I wrote in the main question are not equivalent? In other words I made some mistake?

Comment: @pratjohn the original statement is true, while this one is not. In particular, I think you made a mistake in assuming the convergence was uniform

Comment: Got it. I'll try to check where it got wrong. Thanks for you help though. I'll try to solve the original one with your suggestion.

Comment: And also, can you give a little bit more reason why your example diverges? because I think being asymtotic at some point is not quite sufficient for the integral to diverge. Maybe some inequalities or so that can prove divergence?

Comment: I tried to prove that using your advice and I suppose you are suggesting to prove like: $\lim_{z\to a}g(z)=f(a),|a|=1$ here, by cauchy intergral foumula, for each z inside the unit disk, the integral $g(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C\frac{f(t)}{t-z}dt=f(z)$ but actually $f$ is defined only on the boundary with condition that it is continuous. Is there something more I could do from now? (I messed up with definition of $g(z)$ in above comment. it should have factor at front.